# Getting data out of perl hash structure?

Tags: perl, hash, perl-data-structures

I'm trying to modify existing perl script to support geocoding. 
Found this module for it: [http://metacpan.org/pod/Geo::Coder::Google](http://metacpan.org/pod/Geo%3a%3aCoder%3a%3aGoogle)

I just can't figure out how to extract  data from the hash structure it returns (I'm not a perl coder, this is just some legacy script I have to fix).

```
       {
        'AddressDetails' => {
          'Country' => {
            'AdministrativeArea' => {
              'SubAdministrativeArea' => {
                'SubAdministrativeAreaName' => 'San Francisco',
                'Locality' => {
                  'PostalCode' => {
                    'PostalCodeNumber' => '94107'
                  },
                  'LocalityName' => 'San Francisco',
                  'Thoroughfare' => {
                    'ThoroughfareName' => '548 4th St'
                  }
                }
              },
              'AdministrativeAreaName' => 'CA'
            },
            'CountryNameCode' => 'US'
          }
        },
        'address' => '548 4th St, San Francisco, CA 94107, USA',
        'Point' => {
          'coordinates' => [
            '-122.397323',
            '37.778993',
            0
          ]
        }
      }
```

Tried all the hash tutorials I found on google already, the most I can get it to print is something like HASH(0x91e5558). My code thus far is what the module show's as an example:

```
use Geo::Coder::Google;
my $geocoder = Geo::Coder::Google->new(apikey => 'Your API Key');
my $location = $geocoder->geocode( location => 'Hollywood and Highland, Los Angeles, CA');
```

I'd just want the Point -> coordinates data to it's own variables which I can then write to database.

Comment: The perl debugger is of vital importance for groking perl data structres.

Once you put `$DB::single=1;` into a line of code where you want th e script to stop, then you can do stuff like `p $lon $location->{Point}` to see if you're dealing with a hashref or an arrayref or something else.  Then after that you can use sensible syntax to interrogate that data structure, e.g. `x $location->{Point}` and `x $location->{Point}->[0]` etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
$lon = $location->{Point}{coordinates}[0];
$lat = $location->{Point}{coordinates}[1];
```

Comment: Or `( $lon, $lat ) = @{ $location->{Point}{coordinates} }[0,1]`

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to present an easier to code OO version of this. Since Tatsuhiko did not provide it, I wanted to show it that it's possible to

- bless data structures created elsewhere and give behavior to data structures.
- push methods into a class (package)

So here's the package definition.

```
package Geo::Coder::Google::Geocode;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Carp         qw<croak>;
use Params::Util qw<_ARRAY _CLASS _CLASSISA _HASH _INSTANCE>;

sub new { 
    croak( 'Not a valid subclass' )
        unless my $class  = _SUBCLASS( _CLASS( $_[0] ), __PACKAGE__ )
        ;
    croak( 'Not a valid structure!' )
        unless my $struct = _HASH( $_[1] ) 
           and _HASH( $_[0]->{Point} )
        ;
    # Done with checks, just bless it
    return bless( $struct, $class );
}

sub coordinates {

    my ( $self, $point, $coords ) = shift;
    # Make sure each link in the chain exists ( and is populated ).
    return unless _INSTANCE( $self, __PACKAGE__ )
              and $point  = _HASH( $self->{Point} )
              and $coords = _ARRAY( $point->{coordinates} )
              ;
    We have an array ref here, return it.
    return wantarray ? @$coords : $coords;
}

{ package Geo::Coder::Google;
    use Carp         qw<croak>;
    use Params::Util qw<_HASH>;
    sub get_geocode {
        croak( 'Geocode not created!' ) unless my $gcode = _HASH( &geocode );
        return Geo::Coder::Google::Geocode->new( $gcode );
    }
}
```

Then, you can use it like so:

```
my ( $lat, $long )
    = $geocoder->get_geocode( 
       location => 'Hollywood and Highland, Los Angeles, CA'
     )->coordinates
     ;
```

This creates a quick encapsulation to make it easier to code accesses in the future as well as provide simple changes to the using code.

You could also add this function:

```
{ package Geo::Coder::Google;
    use Carp         qw<croak>;
    use Params::Util qw<_HASH>;
    sub get_coordinates {
        croak( 'Geocode not created!' ) unless my $gcode = _HASH( &geocode );
        return Geo::Coder::Google::Geocode->new( $gcode )->coordinates;
    }
}
```

And then call:

```
my ( $lat, $long ) 
    = $geocoder->get_coordinates( location => 'Hollywood and Highland, Los Angeles, CA' )
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You looking for something like this:

```
$hashref = {
    'a' => 'A',
    'b' => {
        'c' => 'C',
        'some' => 'value',
    },
};

print "$hashref->{b}{some}\n"; # output: value
```